Fall of civilizations
Is the fall of civilizations inevitable and the result of natural laws in human history, or can the cycle of fall be broken by rethinking moral, social and economic principles?

Proving inevitability is difficult; all it takes is one counter example to falsify the claim. There doesn't seem to be any theoretical reason that a civilization could not change and adapt forever without "falling". I will grant that that seems massively unlikely, but if you make it a yes / no question, the only answer possible is that we don't know and may never know.

We do not have data to answer this. Many civilisations have fallen. When Herodotus visited the temple of Hephaestus, the priest he talked to was the 341st in that role since the first king. This must have seemed much like stability at the time.
Let us ask a lesser question: do all businesses go broke eventually, or do some last forever? The health of a business depends on many random factors. It seems likely that some combination of adverse random factors must eventually bring down any business. Where one business fails, others may thrive.
Extrapolating from this, it seems likely that civilisations naturally come and go. The Egyptians were lucky in having a long, thin fertile kingdom with deserts on either side forming natural barriers to invaders. In the end, change came from outside.
From this point on, I have to go on gut feeling. Not all change is good, but no change feels bad. Resisting change for thousands of years by imposing some rigid moral, social and economic principles sounds both cruel and unlikely to work. Maybe that is because change is so rapid just now. If we as a single civilisation managed the Earth stably for a thousand years, stability might come easier as 'this is the way it has always been done'.

A civilization is a living system, an extremely complex organism made up of functional parts working together in complex ways. Like any complex system, it has to be maintained in a universe where everything is constantly changing, including the culture that gave rise to it. When that culture changes enough, it will no longer support that civilization, even if the usual collections of disasters and wars don't doom it. Everything that comes into existence will eventually go out of existence; it is the way of nature.
